# How do I turn off IE's protected mode in Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer-8

How do I turn off IE's protected mode in Windows 2008 R2?

I'm building development servers, and it is just getting in the way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Start > Server Manager > Right side under Security Info “Configure IE ESC” > Turn Off for users + Administrators

[image: disable ESC]

Comment: thanks for the edit farseeker! very cool feature inserting the pic directly in the answer.

Comment: How did you do that? I've been wanting to add images for ages?

Comment: ![alt text][1]

  [1]: http://www.iainlbc.com/images/ie_esc_ss.jpg